# RAW Sockets - C# - Set Flags

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to write an application that sends raw sockets in C#.  I do not have a lot of experience in C/C++, so would prefer C#.  I have found several options for raw sockets in C#, but none allow me to set the flags such as ACK, SYN, PSH, FIN, etc.  Any ideas on if this can be accomplished in C#?

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Update:
I am trying to write a tool to test a firewall, I would like to send out of state packets, packets with different flags.  I am using Win 2008, and as far as I read, I can do raw sockets on it.  I will resort to C/C++ if needed, and so far that is what it looks like.

Further Update:
SharpPcap looks good, it seems v4.0 does not have source, only 3.5 does.  I am going to try and muddle through it, as the documentation is not complete either.  Has anyone used it before?

Final Edit:
SharpPcap looks great! It is doing what I need!! I will post a follow up question, as I am not a .NET guru, it is capturing well, I just can't send a packet from in the capture delegate portion.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Even C sockets don't go down to the ACK, SYN, ... level. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Loki: Consider giving a point to Ryan S since you've already accepted his answer. This will encourage other users to answer your questions if you ask more later. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/).

According to the description:

> SharpPcap is a cross-platform packet capture framework for the .NET environment, based on the famous pcap / WinPcap libraries. It provides an API for capturing, injecting, analyzing and building packets using any .NET language such as C# and VB.NET.

It internally uses the WinPcap driver, so it will allow you to build raw packets with your own IP/TCP headers.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, on desktop versions of windows, you can't.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket#Windows_XP)

> When Microsoft released Windows XP in 2001 with raw socket support implemented in the Winsock interface, the media criticized Microsoft asserting that raw sockets are only of use to hackers to perform TCP reset attacks. Three years after the Windows XP release, Microsoft silently limited Winsock's raw socket support in a non-removable hotfix and offered no further support or workarounds for applications that used them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down to that level, you can create a `Socket` with `SocketType.Raw` and `ProtocolType.IP`. However, I believe you will have to manually create the packets that represent ACK, SYN, etc. So you will have to read a bit of RFC docs. :)

I couldn't find a resource on the web about your specific needs but it would probably be worthwhile to read how this [C# network sniffer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx) is implemented. At least it will give you some idea on how to manipulate raw sockets on that level.

EDIT: As Mystere Man has noted, this is not possible in desktop versions of Windows. However, this should work in the server versions. Here's the official statement from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> Limitations on Raw Sockets
>
> On Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP with Service Pack 2 (SP2), and
>   Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3), the ability to send traffic over
>   raw sockets has been restricted in several ways:
>
> - TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.
> - UDP datagrams with an invalid source address cannot be sent over
>     raw sockets. The IP source address for any outgoing UDP datagram must
>     exist on a network interface or the datagram is dropped. This change
>     was made to limit the ability of malicious code to create distributed
>     denial-of-service attacks and limits the ability to send spoofed
>     packets (TCP/IP packets with a forged source IP address).
> - A call to the bind function with a raw socket for the IPPROTO_TCP
>     protocol is not allowed.
>
> **Note**  The bind function with a raw socket is allowed for other
>   protocols (IPPROTO_IP, IPPROTO_UDP, or IPPROTO_SCTP, for example).
>
> These above restrictions do not apply to Windows Server 2008 R2,
>   Windows Server 2008 , Windows Server 2003, or to versions of the
>   operating system earlier than Windows XP with SP2.